# Extract (ultrametric) distances from hclust or dendrogram

Tags: r, clustering, distance, dendrogram

How can the matrix of (ultrametric) distances be extracted from the result of `hclust` (or a dendrogram in general) in `R`?

The distance of two units in a dendrogram is defined as the smallest distance at which the two units (or the clusters which they are part of) merge.

For example, in the attached dendrogram, the (ultrametric) distance between unit 1 and 4 is 2.36.

[image: An example dendrogram]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are often known as cophenetic distances and can be extracted using the `cophenetic()` function. This function works with `hclust()` objects, any object with a `as.hclust()` method (so hierarchical cluster methods in the **cluster** package) and object of class `"dendrogram"`.